# User input giving wrong results

Tags: c++

Okay well, I am having trouble with the user input from taxRate, when I compile the code I get the wrong results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

long propertyValue;
long taxRate;
long exemption = 5000;

cout << "What is the actual value of your property?\n";
cin >> propertyValue;
cout << "What is the current tax rate?\n";
cin >> taxRate;

cout << "You will pay an annual property tax of ";
cout << (propertyValue - exemption) * taxRate / 100.00; 
cout << " on your property\n";

cout << "and your quarterly tax bill will be; ";
cout << (propertyValue - exemption) * taxRate / 100.00 / 4 << endl;
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, what is your input, what do you expect, and what is the "wrong result"?  Second, are you sure you want `taxRate`, `propertyValue`, and `exemption` to all be `long`s?

Comment: Provide inputs, expected outputs and outputs observed

Comment: for example- propertyValue input can be 94,800 and taxValue can be 2.64, expected output for property tax to be 2,370 and quarterly tax bill to be 592.68

Comment: change `long` to `double` throughout your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error in the code, I'll explain why.
Let's take for example a PropertyValue of 300,000 and a tax rate of let's say 5.6.
You used the formula for the annual property tax rate:

```
(PropertyValue - exemption) * taxRate / 100.00;
```

And you declared taxRate as a long (aka a long int)

```
long taxRate;
```

300,000 - 5000 = 295,000 * 5.6 <----- Your mistake is right here!
Remember, long is a property of int so 5.6 becomes 5. Changing it to a double (floating-point number) will fix your problem. I tested this several times and it fix's your code.